# Minecraft piston door is only shut when lever is on, but how do I turn it off with another lever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

This is a frequent problem I've been having with the designs of some doors. Basically, the door, to be shut must have its redstone to be powered by a lever. So when I want to enter my house I must simply turn the lever off, turning the redstone circuit off, but I'm not able to open and close it from the inside of my by rerouting the redstone? I'm really confused can anyone help me out?

Comment: (The redstone logic is the same whether the door is done with pistons or not)

Answer (score 2):

You need an [XOR gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Logic_circuit?cookieSetup=true):

> The XOR gate is useful for controlling a mechanism from multiple locations. When controls (such as levers) are combined in an XOR gate, toggling any control will toggle the XOR gate's output (like a light bulb controlled by two light switches—you can flip either one to turn the light on or off).

This will allow flipping either lever to control the door. There are many designs to choose from—which one you should use will depend on the amount of space you have for the extra circuitry and what crafting materials you have access to, and is up to you.

Comment: I've got plenty of space and I have access to most redstone related items, I just don't know how I would adapt the circuit to fix an XOR gate, I don't even know what one looks like. I'm not really much of a redstone engineer to be honest with you.

Comment: @user106796 The wiki page linked has a bunch of example XOR gate schematics. Click the [Show] button next to `Schematic Gallery: XOR Gate`.